# "Cannot find http" in Error Handler Service for Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-http-interceptors

I am trying to build an Error Handling Service for an Angular 6 Application based on the HTTP Intercepter. The Error Service should preferably catch any HTTP Errors and refer to corresponding Error codes. However, as I am not so firm with Observables, Subscriptions and the HTTPInterceptor of Angular, the following code gives me the Error: `error TS2663: Cannot find
name 'http'. Did you mean the instance member 'this.http'?` when compiling, in the console.

This is the Error Handler:

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InterceptService } from './InterceptService';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class ErrorsHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  private data: any;
  private error: any;

  constructor(
    public http: InterceptService
  ) {
    super();
  }

  handleError(error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      // Server or connection error happened
      if (!navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('Ein leichter Fehler ist vorgefallen, bitte überprüfen Sie 
          Ihre Internetverbindung!');
        }
        else {

          // TODO: Set Config for Services
          http
            .get('Put Service URL here')
            .map(res => {
              // If request fails, throw an Error that will be caught
              if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
                throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status);
              } else {
                return res.json();
              }
            })
            .subscribe(
              (data) => this.data = data, // Reach here if res.status >= 200 && <= 
              299(err) => this.error = err); // Reach here if fails
        }
      } else {
        // Check the Connectivity of Services
        console.log('Bitte den folgenden Fehler debuggen', console.error);
      }
      // Log the error anyway
      console.error('bitte den folgenden Fehler debuggen: ', console.error);
    }
  }
```

This is the Intercept Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable() //{providedIn: 'root'}
export class InterceptService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  // intercept request and add token
  intercept(request: HttpRequest < any > , next: HttpHandler):
    Observable < HttpEvent < any >> {

      // modify request
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('MY_TOKEN')}`
        }
      });

      console.log("----request----");
      console.log(request);
      console.log("--- end of request---");

      return next.handle(request)
        .pipe(
          tap(event => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
              console.log(" all looks good");
              // http response status code
              console.log(event.status);
            }
          }, error => {
            // http response status code
            console.log("----response----");
            console.error("status code:");
            console.error(error.status);
            console.error(error.message);
            console.log("--- end of response---");
          })
        );
    }
}
```

I am not sure if I am using HTTP Interceptor the right way and how to inject it properly into the Error Handler and I don´t know how to fix the error; any Help or hints would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says it all. It should be `this.http` in your code.

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { InterceptService } from './InterceptService';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';


@Injectable()

export class ErrorsHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  private data: any;
  private error: any;

  constructor(public http: InterceptService) { super(); }

  handleError = (error: Error | HttpErrorResponse) => {
    if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
      if (!navigator.onLine) {
        console.log('Some Error!');
        }
        else {
          this.http
            .get('Put Service URL here')
            .map(res => {
              if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
                throw new Error('This request has failed ' + res.status);
              } else {
                return res.json();
              }
            })
            .subscribe(
              (data) => this.data = data,
              (err) => this.error = err); // Reach here if fails
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Bitte den folgenden Fehler debuggen', console.error);
      }
      console.error('bitte den folgenden Fehler debuggen: ', console.error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I tried that before, but then I get " Property 'get' does not exist on type 'InterceptService'", which I understand, but Angular shouldn`t reference to the Get Property of the InterceptService, but of the HTTPInterceptor. How could I fix that?

Comment: do you have any additional remarks on my comment? Thanks so far

Comment: Right! This method is going to be called by the Angular. So it won't have a ref to this. I'm thinking of something.

Comment: Try the updated code. I've used the array function syntax for `handleError` so that the context of `this` persists. This should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks, @SiddarthAjmera so far - I tried the updated code which still gives me now the following error: "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'void'". I am currently looking on how to fix that error. Any hints would be appreciated, of course!

Comment: How exactly are you using these services?

Comment: I am not sure if I fully understood your question - I am using them just like I would use any other Service in Angular. I fixed that bug, however, but none of the console Logs in the Service and the Error Handler is logged to the console, so I am kind of stuck here, although I imported the Service and the Error Handler into App Module and provided them app-whide...

Comment: That's probably because ErrorHandler expects `handleError` to be defined as a method and us changing it like this would make it a property. Why exactly are you making an AJAX call inside an error handler BTW?

Comment: @SiddarthAjmera: This was a first guess - I am open to any better suggestion as I am not so experienced in building Error Handlers for Angular 6

Comment: Yeah but why exactly are you making an AJAX call in an error handler anyway? Shouldn't you just log something to the console or set something somewhere to show some sort of a message on one of your templates? Making an AJAX call doesn't make much sense here.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below line
import the HttpErrorResponse
import { HttpClient,HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
or
import {HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';